# Hibernate - extract function doesnt works anymore due to wrong type

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, hibernate, hql

Since a migration to :

Spring boot : 3.0.1
Java 17: 3.0.1
Hibernate : 6.1.6
Dialect : Oracle 12c

```
@Column(name = "ALARM_DT")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Calendar date;
```

```
extract(day from (current_timestamp - alarm.date)) < 1
```

Unfortunately, this error message after the migration :

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: Parameter 2 of function extract() has type TEMPORAL, but argument is of type java.time.Duration
```

Does anyone have a solution for this?
How Cast the result to date format.

Best regards

Comment: Since you are beyond java 7, you should be using `java.time` classes like `LocalDateTime` etc. Perhaps the calculation of timestamp - date does not result in the correct datatype. `The source argument is a DATE, an INTERVAL, or a TIMESTAMP value from which a field is extracted.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is perfectly sensible and correct, and your query doesn't even make sense intuitively.

The difference between two timestamps (or in this case, between a timestamp and a date) is not another timestamp, it is a duration.

As an example: what is the difference between 25/3/72 and 23/3/74? The only sensible answer is "two days". Not some nonsensical date like 2/0/0 or something.

So, in HQL 6, the correct syntax for what you are trying to do is:

```
(current_date - alarm.date) by day < 1
```

Where:

1. The expression `current_date - alarm.date` has Java type `Duration`, which is a quantity in nanoseconds.
2. The operator `by day` serves to convert this nanosecond duration to an integer number of days.

This functionality is covered here:

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-Datetime-arithmetic

P.S. You should absolutely not be using `Calendar` to represent a datetime in 2023.